# Servidor no reconoce disco duro externo

Tags: ubuntu, servidor, usb

necesito ayuda estimada comunidad, tengo un server hp ProLiant DL360e Gen8 con Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS, la intención es realizar un backup, que se guarde en un disco duro externo externo marca toshiba de 2tb,  pero no me lo reconoce... desconecto el disco corro los comandos lsusb y sudo fdisk -l y no cambian los resultados, lo curioso es que si conecto un teclado usb, este funciona correctamente, pero aun asi no me muestra ningun cambio en los resultados de los comandos ejecutados, 
alguien me puede ayudar por favor?  muchas  gracias

**lsusb**

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0627:0001 Adomax Technology Co., Ltd
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

**sudo fdisk -l**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1.2 TiB, 1288490188800 bytes, 2516582400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000631bf

Device     Boot  Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048     499711     497664  243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       501758 2516580351 2516078594  1.2T  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       501760 2516580351 2516078592  1.2T 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/webserver--vg-root: 1.2 TiB, 1279304663040 bytes, 2498641920 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/webserver--vg-swap_1: 8.3 GiB, 8925478912 bytes, 17432576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

**dmesg | grep mount**

```
[   16.916826] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   20.174290] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   25.236614] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounting ext2 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[   25.263170] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
```

**sudo lsblk**

```
NAME                     MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                        8:0    0  1.2T  0 disk 
├─sda1                     8:1    0  243M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                     8:2    0    1K  0 part 
└─sda5                     8:5    0  1.2T  0 part 
  ├─webserver--vg-root   253:0    0  1.2T  0 lvm  /
  └─webserver--vg-swap_1 253:1    0  8.3G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0                       11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

**dmesg | grep -i usb**

```
[    0.220105] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.220128] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.220138] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.220188] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.078962] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.082441] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.085878] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.132221] uhci_hcd 0000:00:01.2: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.135953] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    1.137140] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.138271] usb usb1: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[    1.139393] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.15.0-46-generic uhci_hcd
[    1.140618] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:01.2
[    1.141947] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.484024] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
[    1.679400] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0627, idProduct=0001
[    1.680594] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=5
[    1.681789] usb 1-1: Product: QEMU USB Tablet
[    1.682955] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: QEMU
[    1.684125] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 42
[    1.702388] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.703636] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.707748] input: QEMU QEMU USB Tablet as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:0627:0001.0001/input/input5
[    1.710842] hid-generic 0003:0627:0001.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v0.01 Mouse [QEMU QEMU USB Tablet] on usb-0000:00:01.2-1/input0`
```

Comment: Suena estupido pero... supongo que has comprobado en otros ordenadores que el disco externo funciona o probado en otro puerto USB?

Comment: Para los temas relacionados con la rama de sistemas (ordenadores, programas, instalaciones... informatica en general) está esta otra comunidad: [Super User Ingles](https://superuser.com/), Antes de trasladar la pregunta tradúcela, puesto que es una comunidad de habla inglesa

Comment: Hola Capt.Teach, si he probado el disco duro externo en otros ordenadores y es reconocido correctamente, más aún... si introduzco una usb comun en el servidor, este tampoco la reconoce, si introduzco un teclado usb, tampoco lo reconoce, pero si funciona el teclado. gracias por tu aporte

Comment: Hola Parra, te agradezco mucho la recomendación voy a trasladarla, recomiendas que deje la pregunta activa en este foro?

Comment: @Paulo Si ningún moderador te dice lo contrario o te la cierra déjala, No estoy muy seguro ya que puede tratarse como scripts entonces podría tener cabida aquí. Aún así estoy seguro que si tienes dominio de ingles te será mas fácil de encontrar una respuesta mas exacta en SuperUser

Comment: @Paulo si te logro entender, si conectas el disco duro en un puerto USB no lo reconoce, no reconoce tampoco ningún dispositivo que conectes ahí, pero, conectas un teclado, y aunque no lo reconozca, funciona. Eso fue lo que te entendí, ¿Eso es lo que sucede?.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  no parece tratarse de un problema de programación

Comment: Así es Mario, por lo que pude encontrar se trata de un problema de configuración con la Bios, estoy revisando hoy ese tema, luego les comento como me fue, gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Hola Patricio, al parecer es un problema de configuración con la BIOS, no de hardware, si aun así estoy en el foro equivocado Siéntete en el derecho de cerrarla, muchas gracias por tu participación